# Access to environmentObject without variable in SwiftUI's view

Tags: swiftui

I have a class:

```
class ColorTheme: ObservableObject {
    @Published var lightColor = Colors.light
}
```

and I can use it in all my views like that:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var colorTheme: ColorTheme

    ...
}

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(ColorTheme())
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't want to declare variable `@EnvironmentObject private var colorScheme: ColorScheme` in EVERY view. I want to get access to `colorTheme`, for example, by extension of `View`, something like that:

```
extension View {
    var colorTheme: ColorTheme {
        ... // get colorTheme from environment
    }   
}
```

I don't understand how I can make it. I have investigated that I can use `Environment(\.colorTheme).wrappedValue`:

```
struct ColorThemeKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue = ColorTheme()
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var colorTheme: ColorTheme {
        get { self[ColorThemeKey.self] }
        set { self[ColorThemeKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}

extension View {
    var colorTheme: ColorTheme {
        get { Environment(\.colorTheme).wrappedValue }
        set { Environment(\.colorTheme).wrappedValue = newValue }
    }
}
```

But problem is that the `colorTheme` is passed to view as `Environment`, not `EnvironmentObject` so my views cannot receive changes from `colorTheme`. The question is how to get access to `colorTheme` environment object in `View` extension like access to environment value (`Environment(\.colorTheme).wrappedValue`)

Comment: Can you use `@Observable` instead? Also, I'm not sure if SwiftUI can correctly establish dependencies between your views and the environment object if you use a `View` extension like this. Why are you avoiding `@EnvironmentObject` and going against SwiftUI? This might be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: What is your final purpose? AFAIK, the EnviromentObject is injected into the View hierarchy, it is a kind of constructor. And it's so confusing when you want to access a variable that passed via constructor without init (extension). Do you consider using a Singleton global instead?

Comment: @son, my final purpose is not to write `@EnvironmentObject private var colorTheme: ColorTheme` in every view. I want to automate it

Comment: @chudin26 It's only one line of code... I can understand if you have multiple of these objects, in which case I would consider shortening it using a macro.

Comment: @son, Singleton cannot trigger my views to update when it changes

Comment: @Sweeper how can I use macro?

Comment: Look up how to create a macro. And this case is trivial to implement as a freestanding declaration macro. You write `#UseColorTheme`, and it expands to `@EnvironmentObject private var colorTheme: ColorTheme`. By the way, I confirmed that the last code snippet in your question doesn't actually work. SwiftUI cannot establish a dependency between the environment values and the view with this approach.

Answer (score -1):

In your first way that is not a valid use for a class, in Swift classes should only be used when you need reference semantics, i.e. doing something with async life-cycle. Also `.environmentObject(ColorTheme())` is a memory leak because you are initing an object inside `body` which is a big no no! Because it is lost every time `body` is re-computed.

Your second way with `EnvironmentKey`  is the correct approach, but `ColorTheme` must be a struct, and just use it like:

```
struct MyView: View {
    @Environment(\.colorTheme) private var colorTheme
...

struct ColorTheme {
    var lightColor = Colors.light
}
```

If it's not set via `.environment` in a parent `View` it will be the `defaultValue` and if a parent changes it then `body` will be called in this `View` so you can use the new value. Think of `body` like an on-value-changed for any of the lets or state/environment vars declared in the `View`.

Comment: Why `.environmentObject(ColorTheme())` is a memory leak? I don't think so

Comment: @chudin26 its a memory leak in the code in your question because you have `class ColorTheme` you can fix the leak with `struct ColorTheme`. The reason is `View` structs are ephermal that is created used and thrown away constantly, because your init of the object is in body it is init and deinit constantly, which is like leaking heap memory. structs are init on memory stack which is more efficient for things constantly being used and thrown away.

Comment: maybe I don't understand what are you talking about. Despite the fact that classes are stored in heap memory, the ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) takes care about memory management so there is no memory leaks

Comment: Ok here goes... `body` is called many times, on every state change, your `body` has `.environmentObject(ColorTheme())` and inside the brackets is `ColorTheme()` which is a heap object init becase you have `class ColorTheme`. Thus you are initing that object over and over again which is like a leak. Any internal state you have is being lost too. So if it contains any heap objects those are lost and re-init too and your leak is much worse.

Comment: "Thus you are initing that object over and over again which is like a leak" - yes, object will be initiated over and over again, but also it will be deinited over and over again, because old body of view will be deinited. There is no memory leak according to ARC

Comment: Besides, in this case there is no difference in memory management between classes and structs. Object will be deinited in both cases. Only one difference is the class will be initiated on heap and the struct on stack. That's all

Comment: So you need to fix that.